# Reporte con itexpdf y msql, problemas con código netbeans

Tags: java, msql, itextpdf

Estoy haciendo un reporte en netbeans con msql y itextpdf pero no logro hacer que se logre hacer el documento y me marca error y que mi código no sirve ya eh intentado varias veces y siempre me salen errores quisiera preguntar que es lo pasa o que le falta a mi código o en que me equivoque me urge lograrlo ya llevo mucho haciéndolo y no da resultados me gustaría saber que me podrían aconsejar.

```
private void jButton6ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt){
    Document document = new Document();
    try{
        String ruta = System.getProperty("user.home");
        pdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("C:/temp/Reporte_Alumnos.pdf"));
        document.open();
        
        PdfTable tabla = new PdfTable(4);
        tabla.addCell("Còdigo");
        tabla.addCell("Nombre de Alumno");
        tabla.addCell("Grupo");
        try{
          conxion = new Conexion();
          Conection conectar = conexion = conectar.prepareStatement("select * from");
          ResultSet consultar = seleccionar.executeQuery();
          
          if(consultar.next){
            do{
               tabla.addCell(consultar.getStrng(1));
               tabla.addCell(consultar.getStrng(2));
               tabla.addCell(consultar.getStrng(3)); 
            }while(consutar.next());
            documento.add(tabla); 
          }else{
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No existen datos"); 
          }
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Error   : " +e); 
        }
        documento.close();
        conexion.cerrarConexion();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Reporte creado con exito ."); 
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Error  :  "  +e);
    }
}
```

Este es el error que sale:

> run: Error: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not supported
> jet.

Comment: Hola @Schager, las imágenes con código no son bien recibidas en la comunidad, eso obliga que quien quiera responderte y desee probar tu código, volver a programarlo desde cero. La forma idónea es copiar y pegar el código como texto. Te recomiendo edites tu pregunta y lo hagas. Un saludo

Comment: Observa tu `if(consultar...)` y tu `while(consultar...` ves alguna diferencia?

Comment: HOLA saludos recibí el mensaje pero el código no es imagen es una copia de el código directo de netbeans así quedo si pegue el código como texto no entiendo porque no sirve para esto si esta copiado es solo que quedo asi